# What is the point of the term "monotonic" when analyzing sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If my understanding is good, a sequence is monotonic if it increase or decrease.

In my homework, I was asked to indicate if some sequences were increasing or decreasing, and also to specify if it was monotonic or not.

To me, it seems useless to specify if it is monotonic or not as specifying whether the sequence increase/decrease or not will automatically indicate it.

Now my question is, is there something that I misunderstood about monotonic sequences, or specifying it is just useless/was just in the goal of seeing if we properly understand the concept ?

Comment: I suspect it is simply to ensure that you realize that "monotonic" follows from "increasing" and from "decreasing."

Comment: @CameronBuie That is also what I suspected, but now I wonder why they don't simply teach us the terms *isotonic* and *antitonic* as Alan answered.

Comment: Well, probably because it is unnecessary terminology. Why give totally different words for "increasing" and "decreasing"? The idea of monotonicity, on the other hand, shows up in many areas of mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically,  monotonic means either increasing or decreasing, as you say.    The terminology for monotonically increasing is 'isotonic',  and for monotically decreasing is 'antitonic'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not know about these terms. Is there actually a term which specify the sequence is not decreasing/increasing.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I actually just learned isotonic/antitonic in my second year of grad school, they aren't often used

Comment: @MathLearner …"Not monotonic"? (But, given the mathematician's habit of using the prefix "non" everywhere, I'm sure you can just say "nonmonotonic.")

Answer (score 2):

**Definition:** A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is said to be

- *increasing* if and only if for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n<m$, we have $a_n\leq a_,$.
- *eventually increasing* if and only if there exists $n^*\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n^*\leq n<m$, we have $a_n\leq a_m$.
- *strictly increasing* if and only if for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n<m$, we have $a_n<a_m$.
- *eventually strictly increasing* if and only there exists $n^*\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n^*\leq n<m$, we have $a_n<a_m$.

In a similar manner, the terms *decreasing, eventually decreasing, strictly decreasing, eventually strictly decreasing* may be defined.

If a sequence is either increasing or decreasing, then we call it *monotone*. Similarly, a *strictly monotone* sequence is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. We can also define *eventually monotone* and *eventually strictly monotone* sequences in a similar manner.

If you want more than that though and your question is more "philosophical," then I'm afraid there's not much there. Consider what it means for a function to be one-to-one, onto, and one-to-one and onto, that is, what it means for a function to be injective, surjective, and bijective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't worry, my question was not in the goal of being philosophical. I only wanted to make sure I did not misunderstood something as the terms asked to specify in my homework seemed illogical to me.

Comment: @MathLearner If your instructor or textbook did not specify that the term "monotone" has a natural carry over to all of the definitions I just mentioned, then you are right in criticizing or wondering about the "difference."

Answer (score 1):

Every monotonic limited sequence converges. This is an application of the term monotonic.

Comment: That's true, but wouldnt simply any limited sequence converge ?

Comment: $(-1)^n$ is limited, but it doesn't converge.